NextJS static exports and using window.open() to open page on new tab results in 404 error in production
I have a NextJS (v.14) app that utilizes pages router and static exports and acts more or less like an SPA for most things:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    distDir: 'build',
    reactStrictMode: false
}

export default nextConfig

We have another page at /pages/report.tsx. To get to the /report page, we have a different component where a user clicks a button, it runs an async function, and then once a response is received it puts the data in local storage and it uses window.open() to open the /report route in a new tab:
export const ReportModal: FC<IReportModalProps> = (props) => {
    const [year, setYear] = useState<ComboboxItem | null>(null)
    const showReportModal = useAppSelector((state) => state.ui.showReportModal)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

    const getReportData = async () => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('year', year.value)
        formData.append(
            'huc_8_id',
            JSON.stringify([
                '10180007',
                '17050122',
            ]),
        )

        const response = await fetch(`${flaskURL}/main/get_plant_info`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        })
        if (response.status == 200) {
            const res = await response.json()
            window.localStorage.setItem('rawData', JSON.stringify(res))
        } else console.log(response.status)
        window.open('/report', '_blank')
    }

    return (
        <Modal
            opened={showReportModal}
            onClose={() => dispatch(toggleReportModal(false))}
            title="View Report"
            overlayProps={{ display: 'none' }}
            lockScroll={true}
            size={'30rem'}
            withCloseButton={true}
            closeOnClickOutside={false}
        >
            <Stack justify="center" align="stretch">
                <SelectMenu
                    label="Select Year:"
                    options={[
                        { value: '2020', label: '2020' },
                        { value: '2021', label: '2021' },
                        { value: '2022', label: '2022' },
                    ]}
                    value={year ? year.value : null}
                    changeFunc={setYear}
                />
                <Center>
                    <Button
                        className={styles.btn}
                        variant="filled"
                        suppressHydrationWarning={true}
                        onClick={() => getReportData()}
                    >
                        Generate Report
                    </Button>
                </Center>
            </Stack>
        </Modal>
    )
}

The report.tsx page reads the data from local storage and displays it:
import {
    Box,
    Title,
} from '@mantine/core'
import classes from './assets/report.module.css'

export default function Report() {
    const rawDataJSON = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('rawData'))
    const retiredPlants = rawDataJSON.retired_plants
    return (
        <Box className={classes.reportContainer}>
            <Title order={5} ta="center">
                Retired Plants | {retiredPlants?.length}{' '}
            </Title>
        </Box>
    )
}

This all works great in development, but once we make the build for production, we get an error like: Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server.. The new tab that opens has a URL like this https://mywebsite.com/report. That works fine in dev, but on production, the only way I can get it to work is by manually adding .html to the end (https://mywebsite.com/report.html). I have attempted to use trailingSlash to fix it, but that doesn't work either (I then have to type https://mywebsite.com/report/index.html manually to see the page I want). Changing to window.open('/report.html', '_blank') breaks the functionality in local development so that is not the solution either. I could do a very hacky solution, changing that URL out at build time by setting an environment variable for it, but I'd rather fix it for real...
I receive no build errors during build time. This is our build folder structure:
build/
├── _next/
│   ├── alphanumeric-directory
│   └── static/
│       ├── chunks/
│       │   ├── pages/
│       │   │   ├── _app
│       │   │   ├── _error
│       │   │   ├── index
│       │   │   └── report
│       │   └── ...
│       ├── css/
│       │   └── ...
│       └── alphanumeric-directory/
│           └── ...
├── 404.html
├── index.html
├── report.html
└── image.png

We are using Apache to serve the static files where the DocumentRoot of the VirtualHost configuration file points at the root of the project that contains the production build like this, so it should be able to find the report.html file:
projectName/
├── flask-api-files
├── build
├── .env
└── wsgi.py

(Our backend is flask, hence the flask-api-files directory.)
Is there another way to do what we're wanting to do? I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Did you try window.open('www.yourdomain.com/report', '_blank');?

@NotX - Yes, I did try it. Doesn't work unfortunately. I'm actually thinking what we're wanting isn't possible. I think the reason it isn't working is because window.open() takes you out of NextJS's whole routing ecosystem because you're circumventing using things like next/link or useRouter(). I think this may be why it can't resolve the route. The solution is probably reworking our pages and components to launch our async function maybe onChange of our SelectMenu component and then replacing our Button component with Link. Something like that might work.

Well, I tried many, many things including switching everything around so I could use Link but none of those solved the issue because I was off-base in what I was considering to be the problem! The solution turned out to be that we should be paying attention to Flask and not any NextJS routing since Flask is our backend and plays a part in serving our static files. Our VirtualHost config in Apache for this site involves using mod_wsgi to serve the Flask API endpoints. For instance, our mywebsite.conf Apache config file looks like this (many directives removed for brevity):
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName mywebsite.com

  ## Vhost docroot
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/projectName"

  ## WSGI configuration (Flask)
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIDaemonProcess hsde display-name=%{GROUP} home=/var/www/vhosts/projectName python-home=/opt/miniforge3/envs/hsde processes=10 threads=1 user=hydro
  WSGIProcessGroup hsde
  WSGIScriptAlias / "/var/www/vhosts/projectName/wsgi.py"
</VirtualHost>

Then, in our /flask-api-files folder where all our python code files live (refer to my short file tree depiction at the end of my original post), we create our Flask application like this in __init__.py. Notice the @app.route("/") decorator - this is what is actually serving our index.html file from ../build/index.html (a.k.a. /pages/index.tsx). Edited for brevity:
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
from api.config import config
import os
import logging

# Load .flaskenv file for compatibility with mod_wsgi
load_dotenv(find_dotenv(".flaskenv"))

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../build", static_url_path="/")

    # Needed these routes for production since Flask is actually serving the static
    # files with WSGI through Apache. NextJS routing tools are not used in this app.
    @app.route("/")
    def root():
        return app.send_static_file("index.html")

    env = os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV", "development")
    app.config.from_object(config[env])
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug("FLASK_ENV: " + env)

    # Enable CORS
    CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, origins=app.config["ORIGIN"])

    return app

To fix our issue, all I needed to add was another decorator to serve the report.html file from ../build/report.html (a.k.a. /pages/report.tsx):
    @app.route("/report")
    def report():
        return app.send_static_file("report.html")

